# monitoring memory usage in docker

Tags: performance, memory, docker, containers, monitoring

I am running 1000 docker containers sequentially. Each container instance runs a specific job. After the execution of the job, I kill the container to release resources and run another job within another instance and so on.

I would like to get the memory usage of each container. One value per container expressing the average memory usage.

How is it possible?

May be with prometheus, but I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 1):

> May be with prometheus, but I don't know how to use it

Prometheus and Cadvisor is one possibility, I gave a talk earlier in the week with an example doing this using Swarm. See http://www.slideshare.net/brianbrazil/prometheus-and-docker-docker-galway-november-2015

The metrics you're interested in will then be available with the `cadvisor` job label.

Comment: However Prometheus is not efficient when you want for example gather the memory usage for a container running for 3 seconds

Comment: Prometheus is designed for metrics, things that are very brief like 3s are more events so you should look at an event logging system.

Answer (score 0):

As per your statement, you are running  multiple containers and want to scrape each containers memory usage. This can be done with prom query.

Container_memory_in_bytes will give you the complete information about how much memory is used by each container in real time.

Please find the link for setting up the complete monitoring infrastructure.  [enter link description here](https://labs.ctl.io/monitoring-docker-services-with-prometheus/)

With Promquery you can achieve this.

Hope this answered your question.

Comment: do you have an example to do that?

Comment: Yes. As you are familiar with docker, you can create complete monitoring infrastructure with it and as it as different exporters you can monitor with it. Please refer the blog which i have added in my answer. Please let me know if you have any issue.